# Navigation within a partially-shown UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

(This is a follow up to my previous question: [How to accomplish a "90% slide" between two UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107373/how-to-accomplish-a-90-slide-between-two-uiviews))

**The Current State:**

As background, I have a container view controller that manages two separate UIViews (and their respective UIViewControllers) by sliding them "in and out" as necessary:

[image]

Thanks to guidance from @rdelmar, I now have this working.

**The Problem:**

Here's my next question: I would like the secondary view (yellow above) to be "navigable" - that is, I would like to have a UITableView of selectable items that, when touched, show a different UIView in that lower frame:

[image]

**My Thoughts:**

I had considered embedding a UINavigationView controller in that lower frame to handle this kind of navigation, but I learned (via several sources, such as [iPhone UINavigationController inside UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761935/iphone-uinavigationcontroller-inside-uiviewcontroller)) that one cannot "embed" a UINavigationController's functionality inside an existing UIView - it is intended to take over the whole screen.

So, if a UINavigationController is out (and you can tell me if it truly is, or if my above conclusions are incorrect), it sounds like I'm left to manually create a hierarchy, of sorts, and manage how those UIViews enter and leave the lower frame. That isn't the worst thing in the world, but it stings when I think about UINavigationController offering this for free.

As always, your thoughts are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: View hierarchy and view controller hierarchy are different things. Are you sure you simply want to switch the views? If so, there is no need of embedding a navcontroller inside a view. For example, transitionFromView and its variants.

Comment: @NiravBhatt - good question: I'm envisioning that *every* view in that lower frame is managed by the same UIViewController. So, to answer your question, I'm thinking that we're talking about "view hierarchy" and not "view controller hierarchy" - yes?

Comment: Yes, think of the difference from a view controller's perspective: all a view controller does is provide more space to put your views/controls on, and an additional class that will provide platform for your view's lifecycle. Do you want those features? Eg do you like to be reminded when your view got loaded, appeared on screen etc.? If yes, give that view it's own view controller. And off course, you need VC to handle certain kind of transitions such as popups etc, though I am not aware of any tweaks that allow it without separate VC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UINavigationController` is certainly not out :)

You say

> I have a container view controller that manages two separate UIViews (and their respective UIViewControllers)

It's only a tiny change to use a nav controller here.

Instead of adding the lower `UIViewController`, add a `UINavigationController` with the `UIViewController` as it's root view controller.

i.e. instead of

```
// If 'small' is the name of your smaller view controller
[self addChildViewController:small];
[self.view addSubview:small.view];
```

do

```
UINavigationController *n = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:small];
n.view.frame = small.frame;
[self addChildViewController:n];

[self.view addSubview:n.view];
```

You can now push and pop new view controllers onto / off the bottom section of your app.

I've done this in a few apps now (iOS 5 and above) and haven't run into any problems at all.

PS The code above is typed from memory so some method names might not be *quite* correct!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the root view controller to your UINavigationController and simply overlaying the gear view on top as a child of the UINavigationController. You can use insertSubview:aboveSubview: to do this.

This would simplify things a lot for you, since the core of your functionality should be the root view controller.

Using a UINavigationController is very preferable since you get all the animation and stacking logic for free.